# Printing digits of an integer in order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the digits of an integer in order, and I don't want to convert to string. I was trying to find the number of digits in given integer input and then divide the number to 10 ** (count-1), so for example 1234 becomes 1.234 and I can print out the "1". now when I want to move to second digit it gets confusing. Here is my code so far:
Note: Please consider that I can only work with integers and I am not allowed to use string and string operations.

```
def get_number():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            return a
        except:
            print("\nInvalid input. Try again. ")

def digit_counter(a):
    count=0
    while a > 0:
        count = count+1
        a = a // 10
    return count

def digit_printer(a, count):
    while a != 0:
        print (a // (10 ** (count-1)))
        a = a // 10

a = get_number()
count = digit_counter(a)
digit_printer(a, count)
```

I want the output for an integer like 1234 as below:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Could you give a specific input that isn't working, and what your expected output is?

Comment: A hint: first try going from `1234` to `12`, and then use the modulo operator `12 % 10` to get `2`.

Comment: You also have to change the value of `10**(count-1)` - in the second iteration it should be `10**(count-2)` and so on.

Comment: I want to give an integer like 1234 and then print each number in a line: 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n

Comment: "I don't want to convert to string" - Why?

Comment: Also, you don't need to convert to string if you just use the string you already got as input.

Comment: my professor asked for mathematical ways to solve this instead of simply receiving the input as a string and then print by index. So, I know how to use % operator to print in reverse like 4, 3, 2, 1, but when  I want to print in order as mentioned at the end of question's code, it becomes harder and I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using modulo to collect the digits in reversed order and then print them out:

```
n = 1234
digits = []
while n > 0:
    digits.append(n%10)
    n //=10

for i in reversed(digits):
    print(i)
```

Recursive tricks:

```
def rec(n):
    if n > 0:
       rec(n//10)
       print(n%10)

rec(1234)
```

Comment: @DataScience, where are you seeing even one string operation in either version of the code here?

Comment: My bad sorry, this is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the largest power of 10 needed, then going back down:

```
n = 1234

d = 1
while d * 10 <= n:
    d *= 10
while d:
    print(n // d % 10)
    d //= 10
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not able to upvote an answer since I only have 9 reputation, but thanks.